# Is there any OS that can be installed to encrypt the whole drive that has multiple OS inside?

Tags: linux, security, encryption, bootable

What am looking for is an OS with or without and interface that can encrypt the whole drive. So when the pc/laptop boots it boots to this os and I have to decrypt the drive and then I should be able to access the systems that are on the drive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The bootloader needs to unecrypted, otherwise you won't be able to boot. And if you're going to boot from your USB flash, you could use any Linux distro.